# Use Observable to set android:background

Tags: android

I have the following descriptor in a layout.xml file.

> ```
> android:background="@{layoutData.bgColor, default=@color/dark_gray}"
> ```

From layoutData, I have,

> ```
> public ObservableField <Integer> bgColor;
> ```

In layout.xml, I have defined

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@{layoutData.bgColor, default=@color/dark_gray}">
```

bgColor is defined as

> ```
> bgColor.set(context.getColor(R.color.text_orange);
> ```

There is an incompatibility between these objects. I understand I can set lName programmatically via setBackgroundColor(). I do not wish to use this method. I have tried various methods described in SO to convert the int to a text string like #FFFFFF - but that does not work. So what conversion would allow the Integer color value to be accepted as an argument by android::background ?